# Book about a man on a space station who sees himself

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, space

I'm looking for a book about a man on a space station who travels through time and sees himself lurking around, but he doesn't know it and hits the intruder over the head.
He is setting traps for the other person and of course falls into them himself, before he set them.

I associate the story to Stanislaw Lem but can't find any like that.

Comment: You need to go into a little more detail if possible.

Comment: Do you remember anything else about the plot? When did you read that book, was it new then? Any other association (book by the same author, color association, ...)?

Comment: The classic time-travel story with a man who meets himself, and at one point punches himself out, is Heinlein's *By His Bootstraps*, but there's no space station involved.

Comment: I read it somewhere in the eighties. The whole story is about how he thinks he is alone but after a while realizes he cannot be, there is someone else there (himself) so he lays traps. and he falls into traps the "other" person has made. I remember it as quite funny.It's not "By his bootstraps".

Comment: My association goes to Stanislaw Lem, but I can't find anything about such a book by him.

Comment: How about the seventh voyage from [The Star Diaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_Diaries) by Lem?

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/75784/humorous-time-travel-short-story-about-a-mans-dealings-with-other-versions-of-h (about the same story)

Answer (score 19):

In the story "The Seventh Voyage of Ijon Tichy" by Stanisław Lem, collected in [*The Star Diaries*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_Diaries), Tichy's spaceship gets caught in a time vortex:

> The problem was, who had hit whom, and when. The situation was complicated by the fact that there now had appeared morning me's and afternoon me's—I feared that if things went on like this, I would soon be broken into minutes and seconds—and then too, the majority of me's present were lying like mad, so that to this day I'm not altogether sure whom I hit and who hit me when that whole business took place, triangularly, between the Thursday, the Friday and the Wednesday me's all of whom I was in turn. My impression is that because I had lied to the Friday me, pretending to be the Sunday me, I ended up with one blow more than I should have, going by the calendar. But I would prefer not to dwell any longer on these unpleasant memories; a man who for an entire week does nothing but hit himself over the head has little reason to be proud.

Comment: No question about it.  This is the premiere humorous time paradox/time loop story.

Answer (score 1):

Try "Solaris" by Stanislaw Lem. Can't guarantee it, but it was a mystery on a remote space station, and I have a vague memory of it being pretty scary.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is [*The Explorer*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/15818384) by James Smythe.

> When journalist Cormac Easton is selected to document the first manned mission into deep space, he dreams of securing his place in history as one of humanity's great explorers.
>
> But in space, nothing goes according to plan.
>
> The crew wake from hypersleep to discover their captain dead in his allegedly fail-proof safety pod. They mourn, and Cormac sends a beautifully written eulogyback to Earth. The word from ground control is unequivocal: no matter what happens, the mission must continue.
>
> But as the body count begins to rise, Cormac finds himself alone and spiraling toward his own inevitable death . . . unless he can do something to stop it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You could improve this answer a lot by including some more details of this story - at least a summary and maybe even a direct quote of the part of the story in question.

Comment: This doesn't seem a terribly good match.