# Short story about inter-dimensional travel; a boy meets another version of himself, is infected by needle shaped alien life forms

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alien-invasion

I listened to an audio book a few years ago that contained a story about a boy who started seeing another version of himself in his room.

At first he only saw the other, but as the story progressed the two gained the ability to communicate verbally. Eventually, the boy was able to shift over into that second universe even though he could not interact with it.

Meanwhile, interspersed throughout, were news stories in the other universe about a newly discovered needle-shaped biting insect. Turns out that the insect conferred an infection that produced more insects and even larger alien creatures within the people it bit. Near the end of the story we find out that the initial infection is tiny, but the aliens quickly develop a critical mass that rubs against and weakens the fabric of reality.

At the very end, the boy from universe one finds himself in the second universe where he is infected. When he shifts back to his home universe, the infection is carried over.

Comment: I thought of the 1986 book, **The Boy who Reversed Himself**, but I don't think that is what you are looking for... But doing some research, I found a 1985 book with a front cover that slightly depicts what you describe. The book is called **Singularity** but I have not read it or heard of it. Both books are written by William Sleator. The book that you are talking about, can you remember who wrote it?

Comment: I do not remember who the author was. At the time I was working my way through audio books I found on podiobooks.com containing collections of short horror stories by single authors. This story was graphic, contained lots of body horror, and was also novella length at least.

Comment: Well then it is definitely not the book, haha. I went here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/75784/humorous-time-travel-short-story-about-a-mans-dealings-with-other-versions-of-h/182342#182342 before I looked at this question and thought that maybe your question and the linked question might have been talking about the same book :) ...... Oh wait, wrong post. Sorry my bad :D I have a very similar comment to this suggesting a very similar book title.