# Lone astronaut works with yesterday's self to repair space station

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel, hard-sci-fi

I think this is a short story, I read it 30-40 years ago. A lone astronaut on a space station wakes to find someone bashing on his bedroom door. It is himself from tomorrow, offering to help him repair the space station, which is a two-person job. As the space station travels through the wormhole (I think that term is used), it becomes crowded with other time versions of himself. Does anyone remember the title and/or author?

Comment: Ha, I love the premise of this story, good luck. You may also want to check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory for more details.

Comment: [Is it this one?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31879/book-about-a-man-on-a-space-station-who-sees-himself). That has an answer, but wasn't accepted.

Answer (score 8):

This is [*The Star Diaries*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_Diaries), by Stanisław Lem. You’re thinking specifically of “The Seventh Voyage”:

> "The Seventh Voyage", in which a spaceship defect forces Tichy through a series of time vortices, creating a multitude of temporal copies of himself.

Comment: Yes! That's it. Thank you.

Comment: You can indicate that the question has been answered by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer, right below the vote buttons.