# Short story about an astronaut who keeps meeting a version of himself from a different time, possibly by Isaac Asimov

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, spaceship, astronauts

I can't remember the details very clearly because I read it many years ago, but he needs to fix his stuff. He has a repeating day, I think, and keeps meeting a version of himself from a different time. Every day there is a new version and he is trying to help himself fix the ship.

For some reason the name "Lev" is also in my mind when I try to remember this story. I don't know if the character was Lev or, if I am not thinking about Asimov, the author was named Lev.

Comment: :) If you haven't already, please read the [tour] to learn how to accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lone astronaut works with yesterday's self to repair space station](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190690/lone-astronaut-works-with-yesterdays-self-to-repair-space-station)

Comment: @tripleee We need to wait for confirmation of the answer by the OP (either accepting an answer, or at least indicating the answer is correct in a comment).

Answer (score 33):

I would guess you're remembering *Lem* not *Lev*, and this is the seventh voyage from [The Star Diaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_Diaries) by Stanislaw Lem.

The protagonist Ijon Tichy is trapped in a time vortex and keeps meeting copies of himself from other times who help (or hinder) his attempts to repair his spaceship and escape. If so this has been identified several times already in:

- [Looking for an old-old sci-fi tale about time-traveling](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225318/looking-for-an-old-old-sci-fi-tale-about-time-traveling)
- [Lone astronaut works with yesterday's self to repair space station](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190690/lone-astronaut-works-with-yesterdays-self-to-repair-space-station)
- [Humorous time travel short story about a man's dealings with other versions of himself](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/75784/humorous-time-travel-short-story-about-a-mans-dealings-with-other-versions-of-h)