# Looking for an old-old sci-fi tale about time-traveling

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

As recommended, I'm "migrating"/"duplicate" from [literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/looking-for-an-old-old-sci-fi-tale-about-time-traveling) here, to sci-fi.

I can not remember, who is the author, but this seems was Ray Bradbury, however, I've already read couple of his short stories, which would be matched by titles, and nothing found.

So, probably, it is not Ray Bradbury. But this shall be someone like him... `( by date of creation, 1950+ -- somewhere here--  -1990 )`

---

The story starts with one time-traveler, he starts his travel in something like U-boat/Time-Travel-Boat. After a while, another one of him appeared right inside this "Time-Travel-Boat". Okey, they going to travel together.

Thereafter, the third of him - appeared right inside this "Time-Travel-Boat"....

Next one, next one, next one.... etc...

After some time, there were 20+ of him ( may be 600 - six hundredth ). Part of them were from his childhood, and were very young. Another part, opposite, were very old, with beards, etc...
Everything mixed up. And such very-very funny chaos happened on this "Time-Travel-Boat".

Please, help!

---

Q & A:

- Q: Is the story a short story, not a novel?
- A: Seems, it was short story...

---

- Q: By a "U-boat" do you mean it is literally a boat that goes under water, a submarine?
- A: No, by "U-boat" I'm meaning environment of action, something like "U-boat", closed / isolated atmosphere, without any chance to exit from it...

---

- Q: What kind of "funny chaos" happens?
- A: "funny chaos", because all of this 20+ persons - was one man, he knew everything about this place, about himself, about each of this 20+ crew members, about all this story... etc... And everyday life is turning in something very different...

  ---
- Q: Is the story humorous in tone?
- A: Yes, it is humorous, and each new "copy of him", makes the story more-and-more fun... Certainly, It was not a philosophical sight on time-traveling, though, i'm still thinking about this concept of duplication of personality.

  ---
- Q: Is there any sex?
- Q: no.

  ---
- Q: Are there any other characters besides duplicates of the original time-traveler?
- A: Seems, not. Only copies / duplicates of main character.

Comment: The traveler having to deal with multiple copies of himself from different eras sounds vaguely like the 7th Voyage from Stanislaw Lem's Star Diaries (but time loops in that story are an accident, this is a spaceship, not a time machine). Do they have at some point to work together to fix the ship by any chance?

Comment: So probably not _The Man who Folded Himself_ by David Gerrold, which was my first thought.

Comment: Funny how you answer a question with a question there....

Comment: @Spencer, if you are referring to me, I am not answering at all, I am commenting. Asking for clarifications is the point of comments.

Comment: Not everything matches, but potentially could be Heinlein's "By His Bootstraps", which you can check out here just to see if your memory recognizes it: https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v28n02_1941-10#page/n7/mode/2up

Comment: @EikePierstorff No, I just made a humorous comment on something in OP's Q&A section.

Comment: @starpilotsix Almost nothing matches in "By His Bootstraps". It is short fiction, and there is time travel, and several versions of the main character interact. But there are 4 of them, not 20 or hundreds, and there are not in anything like a boat.

Comment: I recall a story where the protagonist "hangs out" with copies of himself (Keith Laumer vibe) in a (U-boat/station/club house) it was a distinct location where only he and his copies could get too. (Initially just a few, but later dozens, then hundreds of him visit it) Time travelers (that's what I recall) or from alternate realities or dimensions. (maybe) They would sit around chatting with each other, playing games, watching TV, etc. At one visit he meets & sleeps with a female version of him. (sex change? or alt reality version?) I think this upset him and he trys to stop visiting there.

Comment: @Eike_Pierstorff, many thanx, it was Lem! Really! Thank you!

Comment: @user14111 While it obviously didn't turn out to be the case, do you know how many times minor details like the number of duplicates there are tends to be very wrong?  Or how easy "most of it happened in the protagonist's room" can morph to "they were locked in a confined space together, like maybe a boat."  Memory, particularly of an old, old story, exaggerates. A lot.  So, it's worth pointing out examples that are close in certain key respects, even if you don't have a lot of confidence. (Which I didn't - that's why I did it in the comments rather than a full answer).  Just in case.

Comment: I feel like "what language was this story written/read in" is an extremely germane clarification that was not asked here...

Comment: @NJohnny The book I was thinking of was David Gerrold's "The Man Who Folded Himself" (1973)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like [Eike Pierstorff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/16087/eike-pierstorff) says in a comment, this matches the seventh voyage from *The Star Diaries* (*Dzienniki gwiazdowe*) by Stanisław Lem.

In that story, Ijon Tichy is stranded with his spaceship in a time vortex, and ends up together with several copies of himself.  The story is humorous, Ijon both gets in fights with his past and future self and has to cooperate them to repair his spaceship.  The necessary repairs are of such nature that they need two pairs of hands, but Ijon only has one spacesuit.  Eventually two of his child versions get into the same spacesuit, such that two handle tools with the spacesuit hands and two with its feet.

The previous story-id answer [Humorous time travel short story about a man's dealings with other versions of himself](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/75789/4918) gives some more details.

Comment: The linked answer is accepted by comment. Due to that not being immediately obvious, and that I feel like this question provides a bit more info, I marked the other one as a dupe of this one.

Comment: Also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31879/book-about-a-man-on-a-space-station-who-sees-himself?noredirect=1&lq=1 is an unaccepted answer that matches.